# Print only the rows which are Modified/Added/Removed in the excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I am trying to find the delta i.e. difference between the two json files
so, basically I am printing the new version of json file and old version of json files in the excel sheet creating two separate worksheet ,then comparing those two sheets to find the difference and storing the difference in another worksheet in the same excel sheet. But instead of only printing the row which are modified all the files are getting printed. Can somebody help me with this ?

Thanks in advance!

Code:-

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib2 import Path
from xlsxwriter import *
from tkinter.font import BOLD
import ruamel.yaml
import os,json
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root=Tk()
root.resizable(False,False)
mywidth=550
myheight=460

selectfile=Label(root,text="File1")
selectfile1=Label(root,text="File2")
selectfile2=Label(root,text="save file")

selectfile.grid(row=1,column=1)
selectfile1.grid(row=2,column=1)
selectfile2.grid(row=3,column=1)

selectfileentry=Entry(root,width=40)
selectfileentry1=Entry(root,width=40)
selectfileentry2=Entry(root,width=40)

selectfileentry.grid(row=1,column=2)
selectfileentry1.grid(row=2,column=2)
selectfileentry2.grid(row=3,column=2)

def open_file1():
    global filepath,filelist
    filepath=filedialog.askdirectory(title="select a directory")
    filelist=[]
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(filepath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    selectfileentry.insert(0,filepath)

def open_file2():
    global filepath2,filelist2
    filepath2=filedialog.askdirectory(title="select a directory")
    filelist2=[]
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(filepath2):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                filelist2.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    selectfileentry1.insert(0,filepath2)

def buttontoexcel():
    global fvc
    fvc=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx",filetypes=[("excel files","*.xlsx")])
    selectfileentry2.insert(0,fvc)

def add2excel():
    dfs1=[]
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(fvc,engine="xlsxwriter")
    for file in filelist:
        with open(file) as f:
            ab=json.load(f)
            gg=ab["Indicator"]
            json_data=pd.json_normalize(gg)
            dfs1.append(json_data)
            df=pd.concat(dfs1)
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="old",index=False)

    dfs2=[]
    for file in filelist2:
        with open(file) as f:
            ab=json.load(f)
            gg=ab["Indicator"]
            json_data=pd.json_normalize(gg)
            dfs2.append(json_data)
            df=pd.concat(dfs1)
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="new",index=False)
    writer.save()
    
def excel_dif():
    df_old=pd.read_excel(fvc,sheet_name=0,keep_default_na=False)
    df_new=pd.read_excel(fvc,sheet_name=1,keep_default_na=False)
    x=list((set(df_new.columns)|set(df_old.columns))-(set(df_old.columns)&set(df_new.columns)))
    for g in x:
        df_old[g]=''
    key=['Name','NeType','Category']

    df_old=df_old.set_index(key)
    df_new=df_new.set_index(key)

    dfDiff=df_new.copy()
    droppedRows=[]
    newRows=[]
    modifiedRows=[]
    cols_old=df_old.columns
    cols_new=df_new.columns
    sharedcols=list(set(cols_old).intersection(cols_new))
    dfDiff.insert(0,"comment",'')

    for row in dfDiff.index:
        if(row in df_old.index)and(row in df_new.index):
            for col in sharedcols:
                value_old=df_old.loc[row,col]
                value_new=df_new.loc[row,col]
                if value_old==value_new:
                    df_new.loc[row,col]=df_new.loc[row,col]
                else:
                    dfDiff.loc[row,col]=(value_new)
                    dfDiff.loc[row,'comment']="Modified"
                    modifiedRows.append(row)
        else:
            dfDiff.loc[row,'comment']='Added'
            newRows.append(row)

    for row in df_old.index:
        if row not in df_new.index:
            droppedRows.append(row)
            dfDiff=dfDiff.append(df_old[row,:])
            dfDiff.loc[row,'comment']='removed'

    writer2=pd.ExcelWriter(fvc,engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_old.to_excel(writer2,sheet_name="old",index=True)
    df_new.to_excel(writer2,sheet_name="new",index=True)
    dfDiff.to_excel(writer2,sheet_name="delta",index=True)
    writer2.save()


ttk.Button(text="Browse",command=open_file1).grid(row=1,column=3)
ttk.Button(text="Browse",command=open_file2).grid(row=2,column=3)
ttk.Button(text="Browse",command=buttontoexcel).grid(row=3,column=3)
ttk.Button(text="Browse",command=lambda:[add2excel(),excel_dif()]).grid(row=4,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you remove the rows, then what do you expect to print? The blanks?

Comment: No i want to print only the rows which are modified in the delta sheet